# Deploying Function Error on Cloud Function with error code 13 and Message "INTERNAL"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm deploying a Firestore trigger onCreate for my App, but everytime I want to deploy, it always Error

the console always showing Code 13 and Message "INTERNAL"

this is what comes up on Console

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
"status":{"code":13,"message":"INTERNAL"},
"authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"[My_EMAIL]"},
"requestMetadata":{"requestAttributes":{},"destinationAttributes":{}},
"serviceName":"cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
"methodName":"google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
"resourceName":"projects/etalase/locations/us-central1/functions/onNewMessage"}
```

this is my code on index.js

```
exports.onNewMessage = functions.firestore
  .document('/messages/{groupChatId}/{groupChatId}/{messageFeedItem}')
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const doc = snapshot.data();

    console.log('------Message Created-----');
    console.log(doc);

    const idForm = doc.userID;
    const idTo = doc.sellerID;

    console.log('Message from : ', idForm);
    console.log('Message to : ', idTo);

  });
```

I expect this will deploy and every time a new message created on {messageFeedItem}, it will trigger the console, but even I can't deploy it

Thank you

Comment: Please contact Firebase support with your details. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So right now I can deploy the function by changing the directory

'messages/{groupChatId}/{groupChatId}/{messageFeedItem}'

into

'messages/{groupChatId}/{groupChatId2}/{messageFeedItem}'

my speculation is you can't have same name to the wildcard

Comment: THIS! I didn't realize I had {docId} twice in a directory. Fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

You have to import firebase functions

```
import functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

or

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

If you did, then check your package.json

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who got this far and still does not have a solution - here is what was wrong in my case

```
exports.fnName = functions.firestore
  .document('Collection/{collId}/SubCollection/{subCollId')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    ...
});
```

Note the missing '} at the end of the document reference.

This caused the deploy to fail with the following on the client

*Failed to configure trigger provider*

And with the following in the function logs

```
"status":{
  "code":13,
  "message":"INTERNAL"
},
```

Comment: I made a similar mistake to this by adding a dollar sign, like `.document('Collection/${collId}/SubCollection/{subCollId}')` -- your tip made me realize my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Set up Node.js and the Firebase CLI
>
> In many cases, new features and bug fixes are available only with the
> latest version of the Firebase CLI and the firebase-functions SDK.
> It's a good practice to frequently update both the Firebase CLI and
> the SDK with these commands **inside the functions folder** of your
> Firebase project:
>
> ```
> npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
> npm install -g firebase-tools
> ```

Answer (score 0):

my issue is because I use `-` character in my wild card

```
'chat/{abc-efg}'
```

I change `-` to `_` and it works