# Error getting a Firebase function configured - Failed to configure trigger

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting this error and I can't find why

Error:

```
Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com
```

Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.newSubmit = functions.firestore
    .document('usersSubmit/{id}')
    .onCreate(() => {
        console.log('new document created');
    });
```

The collection usersSubmit does exist as a root collection. Is it my function or is Cloud Functions having a hard time?

Comment: If you get an unhelpful error message during deployment, contact Firebase support for personalized help. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Please have a look into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60366163/8791788) for the same issue. Please check if you have latest version of the Firebase CLI and the firebase-functions SDK?

Comment: Fresh install as of this week. I seems to have got it working, adding a foward slash before the collection's name like so: '/usersSubmit/{id}'

Comment: You can also post an answer regarding the forward slash to help other Community Member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple! I had to add a forward slash before the root collection.

```
.document('/usersSubmit/{id}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Documenting another edge case that can cause trigger deployments to fail

I have a preferences subcollection in /users that has a single document with the user's uid as the doc id (for simplicity).  I had my trigger configured as follows:

`.document("/users/{userId}/preferences/{userId}")`

It was working fine in the emulator, but when I deployed, I was getting a **Failed to configure trigger** error,

Turns out you can't use the same wildcard identifier twice in the path.  I changed it to:

`.document("/users/{userId}/preferences/{preferencesDocId}")`

And the deployment succeeded with no errors.

Now that I think about it, it was a stupid mistake, but if you're doing what I did...don't.